# iOS - iPhone CSS background issue on website

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, css

I have this site here: http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/

and if you view it on an iPhone or iPad vertically the background ends. If you view it horizontally it will cover the whole screen. My question is, is there away to have the background-image cover the whole screen vertically?

Here is the HTML:

```
<img src="images/index.png" id="bg" class="bgwidth">
```

CSS:

```
#bg { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
}

.bgwidth { 
    width: 100%; 
}

.bgheight { 
    height: 100%; 
}
```

and the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {    

                var theWindow        = $(window),
                    $bg              = $("#bg"),
                    aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

                function resizeBg() {

                    if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
                        $bg
                        .removeClass()
                        .addClass('bgheight');
                    } else {
                        $bg
                        .removeClass()
                        .addClass('bgwidth');
                    }

                }

                theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

            });
        </script>
```

Can anyone help? Or atleast point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably stay away from using jquery to do that... try using a CSS only solution such as...

```
img.bg {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

Src: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/